# XSLT on Compact Framework with Mono

Tags: .net, compact-framework, licensing, mono, xslt

I'm working on a project that needs XSLT on a variety of Compact Framework supported products running WinCE 4.2, WinCE 5.0, WinMobile 5.0, etc. Many of these products do not have msxml installed and although that may be a possible solution, I do not have the authorization to use native libraries.

I've noticed that mono project supports XSLT. 
 - Would it be possible to compile against compact framework? (notable problem would be
   if there's any emit requirements)
 - Is that permissible? And if so, how does the licensing work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked to a lawyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mono class library is licensed under MIT/X11 license,

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Licensing

So if you find any classes missing in .NET CF, and Mono happens to have the same class implemented, you can use the Mono implementation.

https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class

My way is to copy the **.cs files from Mono code base into **.csproj projects, and compile it along with my own source files.